# Remainder of an exponential number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

As part of a solution i need to repeatedly find remainders. % operator works fine if it is a small number or the number is not in form of a exponential. But i think after `1e+22` if i try to find the remainder using the % operator it gives weird answers. So if i try it with `1e+100`, i get this

```
1e+100 % 10 
4
```

Ideally i should be getting a 0. I can't understand where is this 4 coming from ? I thought it might be coming from the mantissa or the exponent but neither gives a 4. And secondly, how should i go about taking a remainder of such a large number ?  Pardon me if this a very dumb question but i can't seem to figure it out. So help would be appreciated.

Comment: Floating point numbers only have about 15 digits of precision.

Comment: You should ask on [math.se] how to calculate this without calculating the large number.

Comment: `1e+100` is A LOT higher than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is `9007199254740991`

Comment: Check the output of `BigInt(1e100)`.

Comment: It is I suppose, but I thought it was interesting that you can see the incorrect number in full.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk True, but I'm guessing he needs to solve something more general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the source text `1e100` is converted to a floating-point number, the result is 5147557589468029•2<sup>280</sup> (a 53-bit number multiplied by a power of two, because that is the format used), which is 10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104. The remainder of that modulo 10 is 4.

Once `1e100` is parsed in the source text and converted to floating-point, the result is 10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104, there is no way for the Javascript program to know the original numeral represented 10<sup>100</sup>. So there is no way to calculate the remainder modulo 10 of the original number. To do this, you must work with the number in another format, such as a string of decimal digits using your own custom arithmetic routines.